Как создать андроид приложение на Dart - Flutter
Доброе время суток, хотел спросить ваше мнение. Хочу попробывать написать андроид приложение на Dart Flutter, но есть проблема что Android Studio недаёт скачать плагин. А при импорте плагина с компьютера возникает ошибка.
Хочу спросить есть ли какие либо ещё программы для создание андроид приложение или же как установить плагин в  Android Studio, если будете советовать VPN имейте в виду что у меня Linux и не все VPN пойдут)
Или же есть врянт писать код в VSCode а просматривать что получается в какмто стороннем приложение?
Спасибо

В Android Studio в SDK Manager в поле Android SDK Location устанавливаете путь до sdk папки, до этого скачав её. В Device Manager выбираете эмулятор. Потом в VS Code устанавливаете плагины Dart, Flutter, а эмулятор будет работать тот, что вы выбрали в Android Studio. В нижнем правом углу по умолчанию стоит Браузер, но вы можете нажать там и выбрать тот что установили ранее в Android Studio. Выбирайте (Cold), что бы меньше тормозило приложение.

Он ещё потребует Visual Studio Installer - Устанавливаем и потом в нём нужно установить пакет один, не помню как называется, но вы можете поискать в интернете или ввести в VS Code Терминале flutter doctor -v и вам он покажет все недостающие файлы и плагины. По ним можете определить, какой вам нужно пакет установить

Открываете страницу с плагинами, выбираете версию плагина и совместимость и всё устанавливается.
В Focal Fossa 20.04 гарантированно будет работать это:

Для версии Студии64 2023.1.1.26 На странице plugins.jetbrains.com, копируете ссылку на flutter-intellij_78.2.1.zip. Через VPN скачиваете плагин (со смартфона ProtonVPN и Tor, с Windows через Tor и TorControlPanel, чем угодно). Также и Gradle-7.4.1-bin.zip

Уверяю вас, если всё выбрать правильно, то всё устанавливается без ошибок.
